# Draw / reveal path on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to build a responsive timeline that animates on scroll.  Part of this brief is to reveal a path whilst scrolling - the path is a series of round circles as in - 
[image]

I need to reveal from left to right, the image is a PNG with opaque background as there are other  things going on on leayers beneath - basically I'm stumped on a decent approach.  Is it possible to reveal an opaque image from left to right with pure CSS or a combo of CSS / JS!?

Answer (score 2):

With this code

```
window.onscroll = function (event) {
    var amount = window.pageYOffset + "px";
    document.getElementById("cover").style.left = amount;
}
```

You can achieve it.

Working Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLse3fez/)

Answer (score 1):

Possible in pure CSS? Maybe, although I doubt it.

If I understood your question correctly, it's easily possible with CSS/JS. Just display an image, then adjust the width of it shown depending on the location window's scroll position, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var total_height = $(document).height();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var new_width = 100 + (Math.round($(window).scrollTop() * 100 / total_height) * 4);
        $('#wrapper').css('width', new_width + 'px');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/095rmnqd/3/